# Ошибка при парсинге сайтов через CURL

Tags: php, curl

На моем VPS сервере функция CURL почему-то не может получить **некоторые** страницы. Например, для сайта akpphelp.ru:

```
<?php 
    if ($ch = @curl_init()) 
        { 
            @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://akpphelp.ru'); 
            @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
            @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
            @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30); 
            $data = @curl_exec($ch); 
            echo $data;
            echo curl_error($ch);
            @curl_close($ch); 
        } 
?>
```

Контент страницы не выводится, а выводится ошибка:

```
Failed to connect to akpphelp.ru port 80: Connection refused
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите в чем может быть проблема? На другом VPS сервере этот URL парсится нормально этим же кодом. Другие сайты также парсятся нормально.

Вывод traceroute:

```
traceroute akpphelp.ru
traceroute to akpphelp.ru (186.2.163.244), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  188.127.239.254 (188.127.239.254)  1.801 ms  1.852 ms  1.914 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

Comment: Например, сайт персонально ваш IP не любит и отказывает в соединении. Или промежуточные узлы чудят. Или еще что-то. Гадать можно долго...

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов можно ли дополнительную диагностику провести, чтобы понять в чем проблема и исправить ее?

Comment: Можно попробовать traceroute запустить, но это не показатель...

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов, вот вывод:

traceroute akpphelp.ru
traceroute to akpphelp.ru (186.2.163.244), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  188.127.239.254 (188.127.239.254)  1.922 ms  1.983 ms  2.087 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *

Comment: трасерт ведет на ddos-guard.net видимо она отсекает тебя.

Comment: @Jean-Claude с сайтом akpp-top.ru такая же беда. Что можно предъявить хостеру?